# Подскажите пожалуйста

Tags: php, java, html5

Нужен совет. С чего начать,какие минимальные знание нужны что бы реализовать такие задачи? С чего в общем начать? Как можно полегче создать такой сайт?

Вот такие задачи

1. Сайт с авторизацией.
2. Пользователь может оставить заявку
3. К заявке можно прикрепить фото
4. У каждого пользователя разные права(Каждый пользователь видит только свои заявки, а отдел по заявкам видит только заявки которые к нему отправлены).
5. Отдел может выбрать стадии заявки и кому направлена это заявка
6. Пользователь видит в какой стадии его заявка
7. Поиск заявки по номеру
8. Если заявка выполнено, пользователь должен подтвердить что заявка выполнена.
9. Если заявка выполнена то оно удаляется с базы

Comment: Вам нужно создать схему БД, обернуть оную в API и этот API вызывать с фронта. Делать такое можно множеством разных способов. Например `Postgres`+`Spring`+`Angular` (я так делаю). А можно через `MySQL`+`Laravel` + `Vue`. Или в любых других комбинациях.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала вам нужно выбрать БД, nosql или sql, спроектировать структуру, в вашем случае это как минимум 3 таблицы (users, roles, applications). Далее нужно прописать поля, которые нужны

users - id, username, hash, salt, roleId(fk), departmentId(fk)

departments - id, name

roles - id, name

applications - id, text, creatorId(fk), departmentId(fk)

Далее, для реализации авторизации нужны эндпоинты регистрации и логина. Для регистрации нужно, чтобы юзер ввел юзернейм/пароль, далее данные отправляются на эндпоинт, там ты создаешь соль и вместе с ней хешируешь пароль, ставишь ему дефолтную роль и загружаешь в бд.

Для авторизации ты посылаешь те же логин и пароль, ищешь в бд сначала по логину, если не находишь - выкидываешь ошибку, если находишь, хешируешь введенный пароль вместе с солью выгруженной из бд и сравниваешь с хешем, если сравнение прошло успешно - генерируешь токен (например JWT) и отправляешь его.

Далее добавляешь эндпоинты для заявок -

/get ('тут ты проверяешь роль, чтобы выгружать только те заявки, которые нужны, также тут в параметрах добавляешь возможность поиска по id'),

/create ('Тут тоже проверяешь, ибо скорее всего отдел не может создавать заявки'),

/update ('Тут отдел обновляет текущий статус заявки')

/setExecute ('Тут назначается отдел, который должен исполнять заявку')

/close ('Тут юзер закрывает заявку')